# How can I draw the attention of ("ping") other Minecraft players to a specific point in space?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

In multiplayer Minecraft play, is there a way to visually draw the attention of other players to a point in the world? Much like the "ping tool" in Portal 2, or to a lesser extent, the minimap ping in Starcraft.

I am mostly interested in using this in *creative* mode, especially when all players are already nearby and I want to direct their attention to a single spot in a room. I am using a Bukkit server, so answers that relate to that are also acceptable.

If it's not clear, the Portal 2 ping tool looks like this: [image: Portal 2 ping tool]. There's an animation that is visible no matter where the player is looking (even away from the target, even on the other side of a wall), and then it focuses in on the point of interest.

Comment: You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @Studoku Which word?

Comment: Inconcievable!!

Answer (score 4):

Googling for "minecraft laser pointer mod" pops up several likely candidates.

http://www.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/laserpointer

Comment: Oh cool :) I saw a laser pointer thread but it seemed to be just a feature request. I missed this though!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to shoot an arrow at the place you want them to look... Of course this may have side affects like killing mobs or triggering buttons/pressure plates.

Comment: Mobs/buttons are not an issue for us, but good to know for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Fireworks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fireworks)!.  It's not exactly the same, since the animation moves *away* from the target, but using several fireworks repeatedly should do the trick.